# Angular route and subroute

Tags: angular, routes

I have an application with 2 features useeRole1 and uderRole2. In my userRole1 app.Routing I have declared routes for example route1/subroute1 and route1/subroute2. I have a page that corresponds to route1/subroute1 and in this page I would like to put a link to access route1/subroute2. What do I put in html to access this wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways which you can achieve it:

1. Using routerLink:

   ```
   <a routerLink="['../subroute2']">SubRoute2</a>
   ```
2. Pro-grammatically:

   ```
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="navToSubRoute()">SubRoute2</a>
   ```

   Now in your component:

   ```
   navToSubRoute() {
      this.router.navigate(['route1', 'subroute2']);
   }
   ```